# Building an Excel table based on specific cells from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am making a table of averages based on a large table in another sheet.

The original table has 27 samples each with  3 repetitions of "sample name" in column D along with 3 repetitions of "data" in column  H through O

ex: Cells D4-6 "22L9" Cells H4-6 "0.21","0.32","0.23"
D7-9 "22p3"       H7-9 "0.11","0.42","0.43"

The new table I want to auto-populate column  A in the new sheet the first rep. of "sample name" from the original table, in column  B an average of the three "data numbers" from H, column  C from I, and so forth.

I have tried `=AVERAGE('Sample data A'!H4,OFFSET('Sample data A'!H4,3,0))`& `=AVERAGE('Sample data A'!H7,OFFSET('Sample data A'!H7,3,0))` and filling down but it does not skip cells in the next formulas

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I understand what you’re trying to do.  Even if I haven’t nailed it, I hope this approach gets you started.

Instead of doing the selecting yourself using OFFSET(), let Excel do it for you by using AVERAGEIF().  AVERAGEIF() says “average only those values from column B in rows where column A matches some value.

Let’s say you enter “22L9” in cell A2, “22p3” in cell A3, etc.

Then in cell B2:

`=AVERAGEIF(‘Sample data A’!$A$2:$A$50, A2, ‘Sample data A’!$H$2:$H$50)`

And then copy that down for how ever many column A values you have.  In my formula, I used A2:A50 and H2:H50, I leave it to you to make those ranges match whatever rows contain your data.